# Can we run pyspark-python script from outside of pyspark shell?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My pyspark script is m.py it contains

```
l = [1,2,3,4,7,5,6,7,8,9,0]
k = sc.parallelize(l)
type(k)
```

When I do spark-submit m.py

```
   SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/root/m.py", line 3, in <module>
   k = sc.parallelize(l)
   NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

Is there any way how can we run the script outside the pyspark-shell I am stuck ??

Also when I launch pyspark and then type:

```
import m
```

Error again comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "m.py", line 3, in <module>
k = sc.parallelize(l)
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but you have to ensure correct `PYTHONPATH` and *initalize* all object you want to use:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your driver program, make sure you first create a sparkContext variable. As I can see, you have directly used 'sc', without initializing it. Then you can run your program:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

import m.py
```